# Trigger in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, triggers

My problem is as follows:

I have created a table in a sqlite-database called `TOTAAL` which will be replaced every 10 minutes by a pythonscript. After the replacement, in other tables within the same database schema, rows must be inserted from `TOTAAL` when a condition is met. My idea was that a trigger could be a solution for this.

The sql-script looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TABLE_A_insert
         BEFORE INSERT
            ON TOTAAL
      FOR EACH ROW
          WHEN TOTAAL.attribute_x = 9999
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE_A (
                            attribute_1,
                            attribute_2
                        )
                        VALUES (
                            TOTAAL:new.attribute_1,
                            TOTAAL:new.attribute_2
                        );
END;
```

Attribute names of both tables are identical.
However, no rows are inserted into `TABLE_A`. What could be wrong in the script?

Kind regards,
PimZ.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `WHEN TOTAAL.attribute_x = 9999` you must use `WHEN NEW.attribute_x = 9999`.
Also remove these `TOTAAL:` prefixes.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TABLE_A_insert BEFORE INSERT ON TOTAAL FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN NEW.attribute_x = 9999 
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO TABLE_A ( attribute_1, attribute_2 ) VALUES 
    (NEW.attribute_1, NEW.attribute_2); 
END;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=532b5bd4a5db3f6da44631cfde5b66b2).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but unfortunately....it did not succeed. Still no rows inserted into TABLE_A. Are there any options left?

Comment: @PimZ as you can see in the demo link in my answer the code works. If it does not work for you then you did not describe and explain your issue correctly.